# Lagrange Multipliers- Two constraints (Minimum)

Tags: calculus

I am given the following: extermum $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ s.t $x+y=z$ , $x+y=1-z$ .

I found that the only possible point is $(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} ) $ and its value is $\frac{1}{32}$ .

I guess this value is a minimum , but can't find a rigorous proof for this (the two constraints don't bound a compact set , so I can't deduce anything).

Will you please help me find a formal proof for the fact that this point is a minimum?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This value ($\frac{1}{32})$ is actually the global maximum. There is no global minimum. Try some other values that satisfy the constraints to see that they all correspond to f values less than $\frac{1}{32}$. For example, try $(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{8},\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{2})$.

Note: My response assumes you've done the work to show that $(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2})$ is either a global max or min as I gathered you had done based on the statement of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need Langrange multipliers?

From the two constraints it's easy to show $z = \frac{1}{2}$, and $y = \frac{1}{2} - x$.

Substituting into $f$ we get, $$\frac{1}{32}(1 - (4x - 1)^2).$$

This is clearly $\textbf{maximized}$ at $x = \frac{1}{4}$, which
corresponds to $\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Doing Lagrange's Multipliers

Define:

$$H(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu):=xyz-\lambda(x+y-z)-\mu(x+y+z-1)$$

and now, as we know, the partial derivatives:

$$\begin{align*}H'_x&=yz-\lambda-\mu=0&\iff& \lambda+\mu&=yz\\
H_y'&=xz-\lambda-\mu=0&\iff&\lambda+\mu&=xz\\
H_z'&=xy+\lambda-\mu=0&\iff& -\lambda+\mu&=xy\\
H_\lambda'&=-(x+y-z)=0&\iff&x+y&=z\\
H_\mu'&=-(x+y+z-1)=0&\iff&x+y+z&=1\end{align*}$$

As it is clear that $\;xyz\neq 0\;$ ,from the first two equations above we get $\;x=y\;$ , and then the fourth and the fifth give us

$$z=2x=1-2x\implies x=\frac14$$

and from here we get the point you got

Comment: From the given constraints we get that $\;z=1-z\iff z=\frac12\;$ , so you can try directly with $\;f(x,y)=\frac12xy\;,\;\; x+y=\frac12$ . Clearly this cannot be minimized as even negative values are possible for the constraint and thus for the functions (say, $\;(1,-1/2)\;$), and thus the solution above gives you a maximum value.